# I need a lemma that involves $n$-dimensional inequalities

Tags: inequality

Let $b_k>0$ for $k=1,2,\ldots , n$ be given constants and define the set $$S_N^n:=\left\{ (x_1,x_2,\ldots , x_n )\in\mathbb{R}^n | \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{b_k}\right) ^{2N}\leq n\right\}$$ I need a lemma that shows that $S_{N+1}^n\subset S_N^n$. I guess induction on $N$ may work but I got lost in the inequalities. As far as relevance to you the readers this lemma will ultimately furnish a theorem that evaluates n-dimensional integrals over hypercubes as a limit involving some gamma functions that I myself find to be quite handy and I will post that here when my work is complete. Now my unfinished attempt at this lemma

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{b_k}\right) ^{2N+2}\leq n\Rightarrow \text{max}_{1\leq i\leq n}\left\{\left(\frac{x_i}{b_i}\right) ^{2}\right\}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{b_k}\right) ^{2N}\leq n$$

where $\text{max}_{1\leq i\leq n} \left\{a_i\right\}$ denotes $\text{max}\left\{a_1, a_2,\ldots , a_n\right\}$ and it is seen that from the left hand inequality that this max occurs when all but one $x_i$ is zero, so choose this one to be $x_1\neq 0$ and set $x_i=0,$ for $i=2,3,\ldots , n$ to get 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{b_k}\right) ^{2N+2}\leq n\Rightarrow \left(\frac{x_1}{b_1}\right) ^{2N+2}\leq n$$
$$ \Rightarrow \left(\frac{x_1}{b_1}\right) ^{2}\leq n^{\frac{1}{N+1}}=:\text{max}_{1\leq i\leq n}\left\{\left(\frac{x_i}{b_i}\right) ^2\right\}$$
plugging this into the former inequality and rearranging we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{b_k}\right) ^{2N}\leq n^{1-\frac{1}{N+1}}\leq n$$

since $n>1$. Wait, did I just prove it? What do you think? Well yeah for induction I need a base case to be true, so there's that...

**EDIT**: Should I be using the multivariate induction proof? e.g. [this](https://www.mathblog.dk/proof-method-multidimensional-induction/)

**EDIT2**: I solved this on my own using bivariate induction, thanks!

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{b_k}\right) ^{2N+2}\leq n\Rightarrow \text{max}_{1\leq i\leq n}\left\{\left(\frac{x_i}{b_i}\right) ^{2}\right\}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{x_k}{b_k}\right) ^{2N}\leq n$$ is not right

Comment: I holds though, not the incorrect statement but the thing I'm trying to prove is true, so how can I fix it?

Comment: I have subsequently solved this issue fully in section 3 of my [paper](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-path-to-fractional-integral-representations-of-some-special-functions-comments.985992/)